# Job vacancies or Job openings or Job positions

Tags: word-choice

Two of my female co-workers in my company are going to leave. 
I guess our manager will hire some new people soon.
I am going to tell my friends about this, but I am not sure which words I should use in this situation.

> I guess our company will soon have some  [job vacancies / job openings /
>   job positions] available.

Comment: I am wondering is it really necessary to put "job" before vacancies, openings, and positions?

Comment: @Cardinal: *openings* and *vacancies* would be understood in context without **job**, but the phrase **job openings** is idiomatic. No one would think the speaker was being needlessly redundant.

Comment: Just to add a nuance: a "vacancy" just means that a position isn't filled.  Sometimes a company purposely leaves a job vacant for awhile rather than rushing to fill the position.  An "opening" refers to a position the company is seeking to fill.

Comment: Hi fixer1234, if I want to know if a company has any job available, would you suggest I use job vancancies or job openings? I mean I am not sure whether it is correct to ask a company's HR by saying this, "do your company have any job vancancies / job openings"?

Comment: Without the "@" addressing, there's no notification of your comment; I just happened to stumble across it.  If you're looking for employment, "opening" would be better than "vacancy" because they wouldn't necessarily be looking to fill a vacancy but an opening is something they're trying to fill.  Keep in mind that both terms apply to defined existing positions.  (cont'd)

Comment: If a person can bring something unique, like specialized skills or contacts, companies sometimes create a position for them.  In that case, the terminology would be completely different.  You would simply talk about what you can offer the company and inquire about whether it would be beneficial to discuss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Job vacancies* and *job openings* are both okay. But the term *job positions* is confusing because a job position may not be necessarily unoccupied and available to others.

Comment: Right. Also, "job position" is still quite rare (and possibly only used in certain contexts) compared to "position".